# Html5 canvas game, creating a map much bigger than viewing canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, viewport

So let me start off by saying I am trying to create a large image or room, say 5000 by 3750, and have the canvas or viewing area only 800 by 599, always following the player piece. I did find a good guide on how to do this, using a background and Player drawn in java script (not taken from a sprite sheet). But what I have is a sprite sheet with the background, and the player, I have gotten the player to work on the background drawn from JavaScript, but not taken from the sprite sheet like I want to do.
Here is some of the code:

```
// wrapper for "class" Map
(function(){
    function Map(width, height){
// map dimensions
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;       
// map texture
    this.image = null;
    }
// generate an example of a large map
    Map.prototype.generate = function(){
    ctxBg.drawImage(imgSprite,0,2250,5000,3750,0,0,5000,3750);  
    }       
// draw the map adjusted to camera
    Map.prototype.draw = function(context, xView, yView){                       
    var sx, sy, dx, dy;
    var sWidth, sHeight, dWidth, dHeight;   
// offset point to crop the image
    sx = xView;
    sy = yView; 
// dimensions of cropped image          
    sWidth =  800;
    sHeight = 599;
// if cropped image is smaller than canvas we need to change the source dimensions
    if(800 - sx < sWidth){
        sWidth = 800 - sx;
    }
    if(599 - sy < sHeight){
        sHeight = 599 - sy; 
    }           
// location on canvas to draw the croped image
    dx = 0;
    dy = 0;
// match destination with source to not scale the image
    dWidth = sWidth;
    dHeight = sHeight;                                  
    context.drawImage(imgSprite, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);         
    }       
// add "class" Map to our Game object
    Game.Map = Map; 
    })();
// Game Script
(function(){
// prepaire our game canvas
    var canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
// game settings:   
var FPS = 30;
var INTERVAL = 1000/FPS; // milliseconds
var STEP = INTERVAL/1000 // seconds     
// setup an object that represents the room
var room = {
width: 5000,
height: 3750,
map: new Game.Map(5000, 3750)
};  
room.map.generate();
```

heres the camra/player codes:

```
(function(){
    function Rectangle(left, top, width, height){
    this.left = left || 0;
    this.top = top || 0;
    this.right = (left + width) || 0;
    this.bottom = (top + height) || 0;
    }

Rectangle.prototype.set = function(left, top, /*optional*/width, /*optional*/height){
    this.left = left;
    this.top = top;
    this.width = width || this.width;
    this.height = height || this.height;
    this.right = (this.left + this.width);
    this.bottom = (this.top + this.height);
    }
Rectangle.prototype.within = function(r) {
    return (r.left <= this.left && 
        r.right >= this.right &&
        r.top <= this.top && 
        r.bottom >= this.bottom);
    }       
Rectangle.prototype.overlaps = function(r) {
    return (this.left < r.right && 
            r.left < this.right && 
            this.top < r.bottom &&
            r.top < this.bottom);
    }
// add "class" Rectangle to our Game object
Game.Rectangle = Rectangle;
    })();   
    // wrapper for "class" Camera (avoid global objects)
(function(){
    // possibles axis to move the camera
    var AXIS = {
        NONE: "none", 
        HORIZONTAL: "horizontal", 
        VERTICAL: "vertical", 
        BOTH: "both"
    };
    // Camera constructor
function Camera(xView, yView, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, worldWidth, worldHeight)
    {
// position of camera (left-top coordinate)
    this.xView = xView || 0;
    this.yView = yView || 0;        
// distance from followed object to border before camera starts move
    this.xDeadZone = 0; // min distance to horizontal borders
    this.yDeadZone = 0; // min distance to vertical borders         
// viewport dimensions
    this.wView = 800;
    this.hView = 599;                       
// allow camera to move in vertical and horizontal axis
    this.axis = AXIS.BOTH;          
// object that should be followed
    this.followed = null;           
// rectangle that represents the viewport
    this.viewportRect = new Game.Rectangle(this.xView, this.yView, this.wView, this.hView);                                     
// rectangle that represents the world's boundary (room's boundary)
    this.worldRect = new Game.Rectangle(this.xView, this.yView, this.wView, this.hView);        
    }
// gameObject needs to have "x" and "y" properties (as world(or room) position)
    Camera.prototype.follow = function(gameObject, xDeadZone, yDeadZone)
    {       
    this.followed = gameObject; 
    this.xDeadZone = xDeadZone;
    this.yDeadZone = yDeadZone;
    }                       
    Camera.prototype.update = function()
    {
// keep following the player (or other desired object)
    if(this.followed != null)
    {       
    if(this.axis == AXIS.HORIZONTAL || this.axis == AXIS.BOTH)
    {       
// moves camera on horizontal axis based on followed object position
    if(this.followed.x - this.xView  + this.xDeadZone > this.wView)
        this.xView = this.followed.x - (this.wView - this.xDeadZone);
    else if(this.followed.x  - this.xDeadZone < this.xView)
        this.xView = this.followed.x  - this.xDeadZone;     
    }
    if(this.axis == AXIS.VERTICAL || this.axis == AXIS.BOTH)
    {
// moves camera on vertical axis based on followed object position
    if(this.followed.y - this.yView + this.yDeadZone > this.hView)
        this.yView = this.followed.y - (this.hView - this.yDeadZone);
    else if(this.followed.y - this.yDeadZone < this.yView)
        this.yView = this.followed.y - this.yDeadZone;
    }                               
    }       
// update viewportRect
    this.viewportRect.set(this.xView, this.yView);  
// don't let camera leaves the world's boundary
    if(!this.viewportRect.within(this.worldRect))
{
    if(this.viewportRect.left < this.worldRect.left)
        this.xView = this.worldRect.left;
    if(this.viewportRect.top < this.worldRect.top)                  
        this.yView = this.worldRect.top;
    if(this.viewportRect.right > this.worldRect.right)
        this.xView = this.worldRect.right - this.wView;
    if(this.viewportRect.bottom > this.worldRect.bottom)                    
        this.yView = this.worldRect.bottom - this.hView;
    }
    }   
// add "class" Camera to our Game object
        Game.Camera = Camera;
    })();
// wrapper for "class" Player
(function(){
    function Player(x, y){
// (x, y) = center of object
// ATTENTION:
// it represents the player position on the world(room), not the canvas position
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y; 
    this.srcX = 1700;
    this.srcY = 599;
    this.drawX = 350;
    this.drawY = 400;   
    xView = this.x-this.width/2;
    yView = this.y-this.height/2;           
// move speed in pixels per second
    this.speed = 100;           
// render properties
    this.width = 85;
    this.height = 80;
    }
Player.prototype.update = function(step, worldWidth, worldHeight){
// parameter step is the time between frames ( in seconds ) 
// check controls and move the player accordingly
    if(Game.controls.left)
        this.x -= this.speed * step;
    if(Game.controls.up)
        this.y -= this.speed * step;
    if(Game.controls.right)
        this.x += this.speed * step;
    if(Game.controls.down)
        this.y += this.speed * step;        
// don't let player leaves the world's boundary
    if(this.x - this.width/2 < 0){
        this.x = this.width/2;
    }
    if(this.y - this.height/2 < 0){
        this.y = this.height/2;
    }
    if(this.x + this.width/2 > worldWidth){
        this.x = worldWidth - this.width/2;
    }
    if(this.y + this.height/2 > worldHeight){
        this.y = worldHeight - this.height/2;
    }
    }
Player.prototype.draw = function(/*context,*/ xView, yView){
    ctxPlayer.clearRect(0,0,800,599);
    context.save();
    ctxPlayer.drawImage(imgSprite,this.srcX,this.srcY,this.width,this.height,(this.x-this.width/2),(this.y-this.height/2),this.width,this.height);
    context.restore();          
    }
// add "class" Player to our Game object
    Game.Player = Player;   
    })();
```

It shows the image and player, but the canvas doesn't follow the player object, It does if I use a background like this, though:

```
(function(){
function Map(width, height){
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
this.image = null;
}
Map.prototype.generate = function(){
var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");        
ctx.canvas.width = this.width;
ctx.canvas.height = this.height;        
var rows = ~~(this.width/44) + 1;
var columns = ~~(this.height/44) + 1;
var color = "red";              
ctx.save();         
ctx.fillStyle = "red";          
for (var x = 0, i = 0; i < rows; x+=44, i++) {
ctx.beginPath();            
for (var y = 0, j=0; j < columns; y+=44, j++) {            
ctx.rect (x, y, 40, 40);                
}
color = (color == "red" ? "blue" : "red");
ctx.fillStyle = color;
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();            
}       
ctx.restore();
this.image = new Image();
this.image.src = ctx.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");                 
// clear context
ctx = null;
}
// draw the map adjusted to camera
Map.prototype.draw = function(context, xView, yView){                   
var sx, sy, dx, dy;
var sWidth, sHeight, dWidth, dHeight;
// offset point to crop the image
sx = xView;
sy = yView;
// dimensions of cropped image          
sWidth =  context.canvas.width;
sHeight = context.canvas.height;
// if cropped image is smaller than canvas we need to change the source dimensions
if(this.image.width - sx < sWidth){
sWidth = this.image.width - sx;
}
if(this.image.height - sy < sHeight){
sHeight = this.image.height - sy; 
}
dx = 0;
dy = 0;
dWidth = sWidth;
dHeight = sHeight;                                  
context.drawImage(this.image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);            
}
Game.Map = Map;
})();
```

I looked around, did some google searches and used a JavaScript checker, but no luck. Any suggestions/advice is much appreciated.

Comment: To answer your question, i would need some more information. First would be if you are going for Isometric Projection (this comes with some problems, but nothing unsolvable)? Second, do you want to generate the map out of Tiles or just from 1 image?

Comment: Why not "move" map while You move character? You know - when you handle character and move it, change "camera position".

Answer (score 3):

I'll give it a shot anyways. So, for the theoretical part:

What you are trying to achieve is simple Scene Management. A Scene needs a Camera, an object that stores the X and Y offset and the Width and Height it is going to display (The Width and Height is also known as the Projection Plane in 3D graphics). In every frame you will draw your Scene (or World) by the offset of your Camera.

To the implementation:

To draw a large image onto a small Canvas, just use the drawImage() function with all 9 parameters as you allready do.

To draw many small images like Tiles, i recommend taking a look at Scene graphs, i wrote a more in-depth answer some time ago at [Collision detection in HTML5 canvas. Optimization too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099845/collision-detection-in-html5-canvas-optimization-too/13100287#13100287)

If you draw many Objects per frame, note that you can always create canvas objects that are not in the html DOM to cache draw results, it is necessary for good performance. A draw call is expensive because of its render state changes and streaming costs, not because of the pixels itself.

Finally, to draw your character on top, you would need some sort of z index, so your draw loop knows the player is on top of the ground, you can do this via layers or storing a z index for your game objects.

So far, you're already on the right track!